# Reduce size of remote git repository after rebasing?

Tags: git

After rebasing and doing a `git push -f`, the size of the repository gets larger every time. I have observed this behavior on both Bitbucket and Beanstalk. Every time I do one of the fast forward push, it seems that my 400k repository becomes 800k, then 1200k.

I trie doing `git gc --aggressive` locally and then doing `git push -f`, which didn't seem to reduce the remote repository size.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the size keep increasing without bound, or does it level off at some point?

Comment: Doesn't seem to level off. After a couple of push, rebasing, and pushing again to remote repository (rewriting a portion of history), my repository has gotten up to 2.2MB.

Comment: Did you try to run the `git gc --aggressive` on the remote repository?

Comment: @RaymondTau: Sure, I'll just SSH into Bitbucket and run `git gc` …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll basically have to wait for your remote provider to decide to gc for you.  You may want to access commits referred to by the SHA1s now not pointed to by any history accessible from a branch (or e.g. maybe a pull request refers to those commits, even if the branches have been deleted).

You may be able to contact the customer service and get them to do this for you, as I know e.g. GitHub has this option (as it's exposed in the admin interface in github:enterprise).

There may be some automated trigger for this if you approach your size limits.